# What is the necklace that Hina is wearing?

Tags: weathering-with-you

In *Weathering with You*, Hina is wearing a blue crystal thing necklace.

[image] [image]

<sup>Click the image to enlarge it</sup>

What is the necklace that she's wearing? Is it just a decoration or...

> a talisman of some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's official or not.

They're called **"Clavis"**. 
Following to this movie called "Children Who Chased Lost Voice" or as known "Hoshi wo Ou Kodomo", in some scene as refer:

> giving Asuna his clavis, a crystal, and fights back. The Arch Angels interfered, annihilating the gate keeper and the Arch Angel commander captures Asuna and uses the clavis to open a gateway to Agartha.
>  [image: Hoshi wo Ou Kodomo scene]

So they're called Clavis crystal / stone. 
The main power itself may vary in different characters and the movie itself, as we known like :

> - Ryuuji used clavis to attract god of death, when to bring alive her wife, Lisa and also a key that allows entrance into Agartha, the actual underworld featuring the gate between life and death (in Hoshi wo Ou Kodomo / Children Who Chase Stars)
> - Mitsuha and Taki switched their bodies in over time (in Kimi no Nawa / Your Name)
> - Hina controlled the weather by praying to the god (in Tenki no Ko / Weathering with You)

### References: [link1](https://infiniterainyday.blogspot.com/2017/04/makoto-shinkai-retrospective-children.html), [link2](https://toonami.fandom.com/wiki/Children_Who_Chase_Lost_Voices).